# How to build KERAS model for time series data?

Tags: model, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, layer

I'm beginning Keras and I'm trying to *build a model* to train over my data.

The data are time series stored in a 3d array like in figure [input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XceDH.jpg).
I’m trying to use layer **LSTM** in order to classify the data, but the model don’t learn! This is the model used :

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() 
model %>% 
    layer_lstm(units = 32, return_sequences=TRUE, input_shape=c(timesteps, data_dim)) %>% 
    layer_lstm(units = 32, return_sequences=TRUE) %>% 
    layer_lstm(units = 32) %>% 
    layer_dense(units = num_classes, activation = 'softmax')%>% 
  compile(
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer = 'rmsprop',
    metrics = c('accuracy')
  )
```

I would also like to try using the Convolutional Layers but I can not figure out how to set the model (the purpose, in this case, is to find similar signals like for images). Someone could help me to define a simple model for **LSMT** and for a **CONV**?

Comment: Your model seems pretty ok. Please check these: 1 - are you sure your target/true data is entirely contained between 0 and 1? -- 2 - is there **only one** right class for each sample, or there may be two or more right classes?

Comment: I can't see the image, sorry. What do the labels look like? (You can upload the image to stackoverflow -- there is an image button at the top of the text editor when you're editing your question)

Comment: 1) In the image the data aren't normalizated
2) Yes, there is only one right class, but maybe I could also add intermediate class
Is it correct to use _Convolutional Layers_ in these cases? And what would be a possible model?

Comment: Because you're using 'softmax', your data must be in `one-hot encoded` form. If your labers are integer nubers (class1, class2, class3....), you can use keras `to_categorical()` function to transform it "before" training.